# How to make the graph of the function f (x) = cos | x |?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using Tikz, I can to make the graph of the $f(x) = \cos x$, $f(x) = \sin x$ , buta I can't to make the of  $f (x) = \cos | x |$

Comment: `cos(-x) = cos(x)` ⇒ `cos(x) = cos(|x|)`

Answer (score 6):

`pgfmath` has an `abs` function. That said, cosine being an even function, cos(x) = cos(-x), so there is no difference between the plots of `cos(x)` and `cos(abs(x))`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[blue,domain=-360:360,samples=400] {cos(abs(x))};
\addplot[red,ultra thick,dashed,domain=-360:360,samples=400] {cos(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was wrong when I wrote cos x (which is a function pair, so the graph of cos |x| is no problem). Actually, I wanted to do was make the graph of f (x) = | sin |x| |,  and I thought  I'd just ask a simple question (f(x) = sin|x| )and, after suggestions, I would complete the rest. When I wrote, I changed the sine by the cosine.

Comment: @benedito `sin(abs(deg(x)))`